# How do I search for "optimal vector"s?

Tags: discussion

I saw an answer a while ago on StackOverflow regarding a provably *optimal* `std::vector`-like data structure, which, if I remember correctly, *lazily* copied elements onto a larger vector so that it wouldn't cause a huge pause every time the vector reallocated.

I remember it needed O(sqrt(n)) extra space for bookkeeping, and that the answer linked to a published paper, but that's about all I remember.

**The problem:** I'm having a really hard time searching for it -- you can imagine that searches like *optimal vector* or based on the tag `vector` are getting me nowhere.

How can I search for questions like this?

I was actually considering posting this on StackOverflow, and waiting for it to be closed as a dupe... would that be considered bad practice? (!)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=optimal+vector+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, but none of those results seem to be that question...

Comment: Then I'd say go ahead and post it.  You did due diligence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Haha okay thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540731/optimal-vector-data-structure

Answer (score 3):

I suggest at least **starting** to ask the question on SO. As you type it, you're essentially doing a very detailed search. The words of your question, the code snippets you enter, will all be used to get you a list of questions similar to your before you subbmit it.

- see the right one? Give up on asking and use it
- don't see the right one? Ask without guilt

And after all that, someone might close you as a dupe anyway. Just don't feel bad about that and be happy they found it.